# Why scroll-snap-type doesn't wo

Tags: html, css, sass

I tried to implement snap-scroll on the page, but happening nothing there's no snap-scroll on the page. Clarify me please where I make mistake in my CSS code. Thanks

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}

section{
    padding: 7em;
    height: calc(100vh - 14em);
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere animi inventore laudantium error consectetur fugiat et, beatae tenetur eaque accusantium.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere animi inventore laudantium error consectetur fugiat et, beatae tenetur eaque accusantium.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere animi inventore laudantium error consectetur fugiat et, beatae tenetur eaque accusantium.</p>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and modify according to your need.... It will provide you full functionality

```
<div class="holster">
<div class="container x mandatory-scroll-snapping" dir="ltr">
  <div>X Mand. LTR</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container x proximity-scroll-snapping" dir="ltr">
  <div>X Prox. LTR</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container y mandatory-scroll-snapping" dir="ltr">
  <div>Y Mand. LTR</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container y proximity-scroll-snapping" dir="ltr">
  <div>Y Prox. LTR</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container x mandatory-scroll-snapping" dir="rtl">
  <div>X Mand. RTL</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container x proximity-scroll-snapping" dir="rtl">
  <div>X Prox. RTL</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container y mandatory-scroll-snapping" dir="rtl">
  <div>Y Mand. RTL</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container y proximity-scroll-snapping" dir="rtl">
  <div>Y Prox. RTL</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* setup */
html, body, .holster {
  height: 100%;
}
.holster {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex: none;
}

.container.x {
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.container.y {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
/* scroll-snap */
.x.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.y.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.x.proximity-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x proximity;
}

.y.proximity-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: none;
}

.x.container > div {
  line-height: 128px;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
}

.y.container > div {
  line-height: 256px;
  font-size: 128px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 100%;
}
/* appearance fixes */
.y.container > div:first-child {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 64px;
}
/* coloration */
.container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #87EA87;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #87CCEA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, and various guides around the internet. It looks like you are missing a `min-height` on the container - which in your case is the `<body>` tag.

I have created a simple [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jonesatron/pen/qBavWOX) to show it working. I used the same structure as your example, just changed a couple of the HTML tags.

There is also a pretty decent CSS Tricks article on scroll-snapping [here](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/)